# Chrome Driver 2.36 Login issue thread is waiting at Driver.URL C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

### Meta -

OS:  Windows 10, Server 2012 
Browser: Chrome  
Version: 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)   
Web driver: 2.36 
Dotnet Framework: 4.6

### Expected Behavior -

In my application I'm using window AD for authentication. Whenever I open application in chrome browser it ask for authentication and a login pop-up window(attached screenshot) gets open. In the pop-up window, I enter my credential and click on login button. Once successfully logged-in I'm able access my application. Expecting same behavior in automation.

### Actual Behavior -

Same thing i have automated with the help of selenium driver. I had used selenium web driver 2.34 for Chrome and Chrome version was 64, with this combination login functionality was working fine. Now recently I have upgraded web driver to 2.36 and Chrome to 65, post this upgrade login functionality is not working. Now in application when login pop-up window opens and application wait for user inputs
i'm using auto hot key "WindowsAuthenticationChrome" to enter the credentials, now application gets hang at driver.url="some url" thread gets blocked and unable to launch auto hotkey and after some time it throw command timeout exception. and when i manually enter credentials or close the popup thread get released and execute next line of code.

**This issue is coming after version upgrade**.

### Steps to reproduce -

Created sample console application

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arguments = new string[] { "no-sandbox", "test-type", "ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-popup-blocking" } ;
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions() { BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" };
            chromeOptions.AddArguments(arguments);
            var chromedriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\TestCases\Drivers", chromeOptions, new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));
            //chromedriver.Url = "actual url" login pop-up window come;
            chromedriver.Url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        }
    }
```

In sample code i'm creating object of web driver with some capabilities, when i'm trying to open my application url where login pop-up window come code gets hang after some time it throw command timeout exception however when i'm trying to open simple page ("https://www.google.co.in") where popup window is not coming code is working fine.

**Any help would be grateful!**